# Error in Grocery Crud while loading page

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method grocery_CRUD::set_js_lib() in assets/grocery_crud/themes/custom_checkbox_flexigrid/views/list_template.php on line 3
```

Code:

```
$this->set_css($this->default_theme_path.'/custom_checkbox_flexigrid/css/flexigrid.css');
$this->set_js_lib($this->default_javascript_path.'/'.grocery_CRUD::JQUERY);

$this->set_js_lib($this->default_javascript_path.'/jquery_plugins/jquery.noty.js');
$this->set_js_lib($this->default_javascript_path.'/jquery_plugins/config/jquery.noty.config.js');
$this->set_js_lib($this->default_javascript_path.'/common/lazyload-min.js');

if (!$this->is_IE7()) {
    $this->set_js_lib($this->default_javascript_path.'/common/list.js');
}

$this->set_js($this->default_theme_path.'/custom_checkbox_flexigrid/js/cookies.js');
$this->set_js($this->default_theme_path.'/custom_checkbox_flexigrid/js/flexigrid.js');
$this->set_js($this->default_theme_path.'/custom_checkbox_flexigrid/js/jquery.form.js');
$this->set_js($this->default_javascript_path.'/jquery_plugins/jquery.numeric.min.js');
$this->set_js($this->default_theme_path.'/custom_checkbox_flexigrid/js/jquery.printElement.min.js');

/** Fancybox */
$this->set_css($this->default_css_path.'/jquery_plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css');
$this->set_js($this->default_javascript_path.'/jquery_plugins/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js');
$this->set_js($this->default_javascript_path.'/jquery_plugins/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js');

/** Jquery UI */
$this->load_js_jqueryui();

?>
```

In controller page i use the below code:

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();
                 $crud->unset_jquery();
        $crud->set_table('table name');
        $crud->display_as('userName','User name')->display_as('userEmail','User email')->display_as('aboutMe','About me')->display_as('donateDate','Donate date')->display_as('signUpDate','Signup date');
        $crud->set_theme('custom_checkbox_flexigrid');
        $crud->change_field_type('status','true_false');
        $crud->unset_add();
        //$crud->unset_delete();
        $crud->unset_export();
        $crud->unset_print();
        $crud->unset_columns('userpassword','albumOrder','albumsPerPage','albumsPerPageAdmin','friendsPerPage','keepUpdated','sendAdminUpdates','userType');
        $crud->edit_fields('userName','userEmail','aboutMe','status');
        $output =$crud->render();
        $css_files=array();
        $js_files=array();
        $css_files=array_merge($css_files,$output->css_files);
        $js_files=array_merge($js_files,$output->js_files);
        $title="Search users";
        $head_data = array('username'=>'','last_login'=>'','js_files' =>$js_files, 'css_files' =>$css_files,'title'=>$title);
        $body_data=array('output' => $output->output);
        $this->load->view('admin/header',$head_data);
        $this->load->view('admin/searchuser',$body_data);
        $this->load->view('admin/footer');
```

where grocery crud use that pages shows the same error .
If i try to add  $crud->unset_jquery(); i shows the same error

also add 
$crud->set_js_lib('admin/assets/grocery_crud/js/'.grocery_CRUD::JQUERY);
                     $crud->set_default_javascript_path('admin/assets/grocery_crud/js');
it shows the eeror so i comment these two line and add unset_jquery but no effects, same error

Comment: when i try to load the page then it show   "Fatal error: Call to undefined method grocery_CRUD::set_js_lib() in public_html/admin/assets/grocery_crud/themes/custom_checkbox_flexigrid/views/list_template.php on line 3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this in your code..

`$crud = new grocery_crud();
 $crud->unset_jquery();`

Comment: i extend my question with full code so please look that

Comment: try putting `unset_jquery()` in the end of the code.. and also try commenting `$this->load_js_jqueryui();` this line...

Comment: commenting $this->load_js_jqueryui(); and simply use set_js then it work perfectly. but try to edit it show the content and also two error.   A PHP Error was encountered,
Severity: Notice,
Message: Undefined variable: is_ajax,
Filename: views/edit.php,
Line Number: 51,

Comment: may be you haven't included ajax files in your view page... @FirozP.J